# why mysql query work on phpmyadmin but error on php

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, php

i have a sql query that work on phpmyadmin  without problem but SQL syntax Error on php mysql_Query

query:

```
   SELECT `_id` INTO @task_id  
   FROM `SepidarSoft_Portal`.`Permission` 
   WHERE `FID`='1' and `GID`='Request' and `Permission`='Client' ;

   INSERT INTO `SepidarSoft_Portal`.`Permission` 
   SET `_id`=@task_id,`CTime`='1362128156',`CUser`='1',`FID`='1',`KFID`='0',`GID`='Request',`KGID`='1',`Permission`='Client',`Expired`='0',`Direction`='1',`Access`='200',`State`='1' 
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `CTime`='1362128156',`CUser`='1',`FID`='1',`KFID`='0',`GID`='Request',`KGID`='1',`Permission`='Client',`Expired`='0',`Direction`='1',`Access`='200',`State`='1'
```

mysql_query show this error

> Add You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `SepidarSoft_Portal`.`Permission` SET  `_id`=@task_id,`CTime`='13621' at line 2

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Are you trying to run both queries into `single mysql_query()` ?

Comment: Try executing them as single statements and not together at once.

Comment: so you posted sql query that work,and not PHP code that is not working?

Comment: @GBD yes query Run in one mysql_query()

Comment: @BojanKovacevic this query  is the input of mysql_query()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)**
>
> mysql_query() **sends a unique query** (multiple queries are not
>   supported) to the currently active database on the server that's
>   associated with the specified link_identifier.

**Therefore execute your statements separately**, which is safer.

Or if you stick with `mysql_*` extension you can use `mysqli_multi_query()`

> **[mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)**
>
> Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a
>   semicolon.

But you better off switch to `PDO` or `mysqli_*` extension. `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute both queries in a separate commands. Also don't listen to those who advice you to use `mysql_query()` as this is **deprecated**. Use [mysqli_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run them as 2 separate sql queries in PHP. So use 2 mysql_query() statements and you will no longer get the error.

Also, you should look to upgrade your code to no longer use mysql_ statements as they are deprecated, but to use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: why it run correctly on phpmyadmin

Comment: GBD gave you the answer why

Comment: PHP's mysql_query() function can only run one statement at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is why:

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not
>   supported) to the currently active database on the server that's
>   associated with the specified link_identifier.

**Note that:** Try to avoid the MySQL extenstions, try to use PDO or prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use below this:

```
INSERT INTO epidarSoft_Portal`.`Permission
         (column1, column2, column3, column4)
     VALUES
         ('" . $val1 . "',  '" . $val2 . "', '" . $val3 . "', '" . $val4 . "')
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
         column2='" . $val2 . "',
         column3='" . $val3 . "',
         column4='" . $val4 . "'"
 );
```

Comment: we can use SET  keyword but problem was for multi query with mysql_query